# Android Studio tab switcher: sort by name?

Tags: android-studio, intellij-idea, interface

Can someone suggest how to sort files in the right pane alphabetically?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this also applies to the "Switcher" but I found this option:

[image]

Comment: Has no effect on the Switcher, unfortunately.

Answer (score -2):

I am not a familiar with Android Studio so i might be wrong but aren't the files stored in the File Explorer. Then just go to that location in your files and select View then Sort By:
[image]

Again i might be wrong